# how to speed up file_get_contents and json_decode

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents

I'm currently working on a fansite(just for my purposes) which gets all it's data from different APIs like this:

```
$newjson = file_get_contents(LINK_TO_JSON_HERE);
$newarr = json_decode($newjson);
```

My Problem with this: currently the site loads 13 different (huge)JSON-files, which slows the site down very much. The loading takes up to 30-45 seconds, which isn't really acceptable, but I tried to get it working before optimizing it. Is it possible to speed this up by using other functions? Seeing other fansites loading the same content within 1 second made me asking.
About the functionality: I load the whole JSON into the array and then take out the info I need, which is often less than 1% of the JSON-file's text. Is there a way to filter the things I need before loading the whole document into an array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that is a json data you don't actually need php.. Just load the page and on document.ready start getting json data from those files and use it by js Thats why Js is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odds are very high that the JSON is not slowing you down but just the `file_get_contents()`. Benchmark your issue properly so that you are not wasting your time optimizing the wrong thing.

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
$newjson = file_get_contents(LINK_TO_JSON_HERE);
echo 'file_get_contents('.htmlentities($LINK_TO_JSON_HERE).'): '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br>';

$start = microtime(true);
$newarr = json_decode($newjson);
echo 'json_decode(): '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br><br>';
```

Anyways, the best way to maintain real-time data and get better speed is to switch to [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

I'm not sure how often the data is updated on these APIs so you could also develop some sort of caching mechanism which fetches the data a few times per day and saves it locally to a JSON file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I know which of the files is the slowest to load. For example https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/data/character/achievements?locale=en_GB&apikey=API_KEY_HERE (you need an API-Key to view it) takes 4,6seconds to load. I'll look into `curl_multi_exec()` now, maybe this can help me.

Comment: @neverlucky If 4.6 seconds is your slowest API then `curl_multi_exec()` will only be able to get your page loads times down to 4.6 seconds at best. You will need to either find a faster API or implement a caching mechanism.

Comment: @neverlucky Any luck with this?

Comment: I solved it a different way. Some of the APIs never change so I put them into local txt-files, which can be read way faster. And instead of doing one request for each field, i wrote them into one file_get_contents like `?fields=guild,talents,titles` instead of one for `?fields=guild`, one for `?fields=talents` and so on, which also increased the speed. Now the page loads in under 1 second, down from 30.

Comment: @neverlucky Nice! If you feel that my answer helped you achieve that result then feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of the speed of functions, but about waiting for a response from the opposite server. If its possible you can cache the data.

Comment: That is not what the question was about. @neverlucky asked about filtering the JSON files, not caching them. I get your point, but it doesn't answer the question.